# Spring security on endpoint using Cognito IAM role?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, amazon-cognito

I am trying to restrict specific endpoints on a Spring boot service depending on what role they have set in the OAuth2 credentials.

This is the endpoint

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/admin")
public class AdminController {

    @GetMapping(produces = "application/json")
    public TestResponse get() {
        return new TestResponse("Admin API Response");
    }
}
```

This is then secured using SecurityConfiguration bean

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.csrf()
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/login", "/", "/home", "/logout", "/ping").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/api/admin").hasRole("arn:aws:iam::xxxxxx:role/spring-sso-test-ADMIN")
            .antMatchers("/api/user").hasRole("arn:aws:iam::xxxxxx:role/spring-sso-test-USER")
            .and()
            .oauth2Login()
            .and()
            .logout()
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/logout");
    }
}
```

I debugged the Principal and can see the correct IAM role in the list of attributes `cognito:roles` list

[image: aws cognito spring security principal]

However when I hit the endpoint I get a HTTP 403 Unauthorized. Meaning that the user has authenticated successfully, but Spring does not recognize or understand the attributes or how to map them?

I tried using the @Secured annotation but that didn't change anything.

```
@Secured("arn:aws:iam::xxxxxx:role/spring-sso-test-ADMIN")
@GetMapping(produces = "application/json")
public TestResponse get() {
        return new TestResponse("Admin API Response");
}
```

How do I allow this to work using an IAM role defined in AWS Cognito?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use the `hasRole` DSL method, Spring Security adds the `ROLE_` prefix to your authority. So, the authority `arn:aws:iam::xxxxxx:role/spring-sso-test-ADMIN` will become `ROLE_arn:aws:iam::xxxxxx:role/spring-sso-test-ADMIN`.

You should use the `hasAuthority` method instead.

Additionally, you should take the `cognito:roles` from the `attributes` and add in the `authorities`, since it's the property that Spring Security will query to get the authorities.

To map the authorities you can use a `OAuth2UserService`:

```java
@Bean
SecurityFilterChain app(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .oauth2Login(oauth2 -> oauth2
                .userInfoEndpoint(userInfo -> userInfo
                    .oidcUserService(this.oidcUserService())
                    ...
                )
            );
    return http.build();
}

private OAuth2UserService<OidcUserRequest, OidcUser> oidcUserService() {
    // your custom implementation
}
```

More details in the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/oauth2/login/advanced.html#oauth2login-advanced-map-authorities).

Comment: I just tried this `hasAuthority("arn:aws:iam::xxxxxx:role/spring-sso-test-ADMIN")` but still getting a HTTP 403

Comment: Add `logging.level.org.springframework.security=TRACE`  to your `application.properties`  and paste the logs in your question

Comment: See my updated answer